# powershell add extra /r/n

Tags: json, git, powershell, newline, trailing-newline

I try to replace some value in the json file, and then submit the update json file to the git repo. But the json file add extra `\r\n`.

My test scripts is below:

```
   $TempFile = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\LogicApp\workflows\$WorkflowName\workflow.json"

   $WorkflowForParametersupdate = (Get-Content -Path "$TempFile" -Raw) -replace $Devobj.Value,$($_.Value) | ConvertFrom-Json
   $WorkflowForParametersupdate = $WorkflowForParametersupdate | ConvertTo-Json -depth 100 | Out-File -FilePath $TempFile -Force
```

Then I submit those files back to my git repo by git command:

```
cd $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
cd LogicApp\Workflows
git config --global user.email "XXXXX"
git config --global user.name "XXXXX"
git add *
git commit -m "Add workflow deploy files"
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $(System.AccessToken)" push
git push https://$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/XXXXX/_git/XXX-XXXXXHEAD:SIT
```

But the result will be added `\r\n`:

[image]

How to resolve this issue? I do not want to replace those `\r\n`, I want just not add them to the git repo at first.

Comment: `/r/n` or `\r\n` ?